# multi variable optimization with cvxpy

Tags: python, cvxpy

- X is T by m matrix (Given Matrix)
- B is T by n matrix (Variable 1)
- A is n by m matrix (Variable 2)

I want to minimize ||X-A*B|| forbinious norm and find A and B for that using Python / cvxpy

I did this on Matlab and works fine

Discriminative disaggregation sparse coding for energy disaggregation algorithm was successfully implemented on Matlab but difficult to use for large sample sets, So need to implement it on python

import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

```
n = 5
m = 4
T = 3
np.random.seed(1)
A = cp.Variable((n, m))
B = cp.Variable((T, n))
x = np.random.rand(T, m)

constraints = [A >= 0,
           B >= 0]


obj = cp.Minimize(cp.norm(x - cp.matmul(B,A),"fro"))
prob = cp.Problem(obj,constraints)

prob.solve()
```

Need to use cvxpy or any other tool on python to minimize multi objective function

Comment: This problem doesn't follow DCP. Can you share the matlab code? Were you using CVX?

Comment: Hi Jacques, Can you kindly share your contact to madhawa.herath@gmail.com, Code is too lengthy and not allowed to share by the page

Comment: cvx_begin quiet
    variable A(n, m);
        minimize( power(2,norm((X - BCT_Normalized*A),'fro')) + lambda * (sum(A(:))) );
        subject to 
    A >= 0; 
  cvx_end